# Where can I find documentation on SPI2STATbits?

Tags: pic, spi, pic24

I've recently come across spi2statbits in the following function:

```
int WriteSPI2( int data)

{
    int f;
    SPI2BUF = data;                 // write to buffer for TX
    while( !SPI2STATbits.SPIRBF)  
    {f=1;}// wait transfer completion
    return SPI2BUF;                 // read the received value
} // WriteSPI2
```

I'm using the above in conjunction with a PIC24FJ128GA010 project.

I've been searching around to find more about SPI2STATbits but haven't found actual documentation.  I assume this is a fairly basic requirement.

Can someone direct me to the correct documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See page 130 of [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39747F.pdf) , look for `SPIxSTAT`.

For the particular device, do a search for SPI2STATbits in all included header files.

It's in `p24FJ128GA010.h` as

```
#define SPI2STAT SPI2STAT extern volatile uint16_t SPI2STAT __attribute__((__sfr__)); __extension__ typedef struct tagSPI2STATBITS {...
```

Comment: If this post answers, please mark this post as an answer.

Comment: what is the difference between SPIxSTAT and SPIxSTATbits? I can't watch SPIxSTATbits but I can watch SPIxSTAT.  SPIxSTATbits is not listed in the documentations....

Comment: `SPIxSTATbits` are only used in code to refer to the bits of `SPIxSTAT`

Comment: Where can I find information about keywords such as bits?

Comment: Do a search for `SPI2STATbits` in all included header files.

Comment: `SPI2STATbits` is a structure that breaks up `SPI2STAT` into its individual bits. If you are using MPLAB X, right right-click and select "Nagivate|Go to declaration". You should have xc.h as an include file (in turn, it selects the specific register definition file for your processor).

Comment: wow! Thanks!  It's in `p24FJ128GA010.h` as `#define SPI2STAT SPI2STAT
extern volatile uint16_t  SPI2STAT __attribute__((__sfr__));
__extension__ typedef struct tagSPI2STATBITS {`  CAn you add above to answer and I will accept?